# 'php artisan db:seed' doesn't work in Laravel5.4

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have started learning laravel 5.4. In order to populate my db, I complete BreedsTableSeeder.php file.

```
enter code here
class BreedsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run() {
        DB::table('breeds')->insert([
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => "Domestic"],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => "Persian"],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => "Siamese"],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => "Abyssinian"],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then I complete DatabaseSeeder.php.

```
enter code here
<?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
        public function run() {
            $this->call(BreedsTableSeeder::class);
        }
    }  
?>
```

Then, I seed the database by calling it, using the following command.

> $ php artisan db:seed

but error occurs as follows

> *
>     [ReflectionException]
>     Class BreedsTableSeeder does not exist*

When I use,

> php artisan db:seed --class="BreedsTableSeeder"

the result is the same.

When I use,

> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; on DatabaseSeeder.php file

it is automatically deleted.

Comment: can you post the whole code of your seeder? i assume you just lack the correct namespace or use statements at the top. `use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
composer dumpautoload
```

once you create new classes

**EDIT**

> error occurs like this. "Class 'Seeder' not found

Your seeder lacks

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you explain in detail?

Comment: I have done with $composer dumpautoload, and seed the database again. $php artisan db:seed. error occurs like this. "Class 'Seeder' not found"

Comment: you most likely lacks required `use`. See example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding#writing-seeders

Comment: I'm trying to add use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; but it was deleted automatically.

Comment: Model is irrelevant if you do not use it. `Seeder` is important.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. Now i solved.

And you need to run in your console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to generate new class map and then run:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I've just tested it. It is working without a problem in Laravel 5